# In a Serverless project, how can one get the ARN of one Lambda function deployed a the project to another in the same project?

Tags: serverless-framework, aws-serverless, cross-reference

I'm working on a web service in which one Lambda function serves requests from a web browser. This request handling kicks off some slow work that can be completed asynchronously, so I have a separate Lambda function that I want to invoke asynchronously to handle the slow work.

This is being deployed as a [Serverless](https://serverless.com/) project. The serverless.yml file looks like this:

```
service: AsyncService

frameworkVersion: '=1.54.0'

provider:
  name: aws
  runtime: go1.x

package:
  exclude:
    - ./**
  include:
    - ./bin/**

functions:
  FrontEnd:
    handler: bin/FrontEnd
    events:
      - http:
          path: processData
          method: post    
    environment:
      AsyncWorkerARN: ???

  AsyncWorker:
    handler: bin/AsyncWorker
```

The question is how can I get the ARN of the `AsyncWorker` Lambda function into an environment variable of the FrontEnd Lambda function without hardcoding it? I need it there to be able to [invoke](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-go/api/service/lambda/#InvokeInput) the AsyncWorker Lambda.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the best way is to use the [serverless-pseudo-parameters plugin](https://serverless.com/plugins/serverless-pseudo-parameters/) and then do something like: `arn:aws:lambda:#{AWS::Region}:#{AWS::AccountId}:function:AsyncService-dev-AsyncWorker`

Comment: This is essentially what I ended up doing (without the plugin) by computing the ARN in the `custom` section with a `Fn::Join` and a bunch of `Ref:` statements.